# Dismiss a custom dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I'm trying to make a custom dialog to show a view in this dialog. This is the Builder code:

```
//Getting the layout
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_simple,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.rlDialogSimple));

//Change Text and on click
TextView tvDialogSimple = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvDialogSimple);
tvDialogSimple.setText(R.string.avisoComprobar);
Button btDialogSimple = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btDialogSimple);
btDialogSimple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do some stuff

        //Here i want to close the dialog
    }
});

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AcPanelEditor.this);
builder.setView(layout);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

So, i want to dismiss the dialog in the onClick of btDialogSimple. How i can do it? I don't know how to call the dismiss method from inside a onclicklistener.

My buttons have a custom layout, so i don't want to make a builder.setPositiveButton.

Any ideas?

Comment: Great question! This is exactly the way is *seems* that it should work. But of course, it doesn't--that'd just be easy! (not the Android Way).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to save the AlertDialog to your parent class property, then use something like this:

```
class parentClass ........ {
private AlertDialog alert=null;
........
public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do some stuff

        //Here i want to close the dialog
        if (parentClass.this.alert!=null)            
        parentClass.this.alert.dismiss();
    }
........
this.alert = builder.create();
this.alert.show();
```

}

Comment: Works for me, too. But since I have a custom dialog built as an xml file, I don't need to Build it, just use setContentView(custom_dialog).

Comment: @pentium10... I am getting same issue but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 7):

I think a better way may be to call

```
dismissDialog(DIALOG_ID);
```

Wouldn't making the AlertDialog a class property defeat the purpose of returning a Dialog from the onCreateDialog()?

Answer (score 0):

ı am using

```
public  Dialog dialog;

buton_sil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @ Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                   DialogClose();
                   }
}):


public void DialogClose() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AlertDialog` instance e.g. `mAlertDialog` as a global variable. And call `mAlertDialog.dismiss();` inside `onClick()`