# setOnClickListener raise error inside in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dismiss a custom dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825272/dismiss-a-custom-dialog)

I have a customized dialog, the layout file of the dialog contains a button with **id** "`submit_btn`".

In java code, I `setOnClickListener` to the `submit_btn` button of the dialog:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_dialog, null);

AlertDialog infoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                                           .setView(view)        
                                           .create();
infoDialog.show();  

Button submitBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);

submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
       //ERROR: Cannot refer to a non-final variable infoDialog inside an inner class defined in a different method

                     infoDialog.dismiss();
       }
});
```

Then, when I call `infoDialog.dismiss();`, Eclipse raise the error which complains that  `Cannot refer to a non-final variable infoDialog inside an inner class defined in a different method`. How to get rid of this problem based on my code?

Comment: duplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825272/dismiss-a-custom-dialog

Comment: I made an edit to my answer if you are against making it final. Is there a reason you don't want to mark it final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just do this...

```
final AlertDialog infoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                                           .setView(view)        
                                           .create();

// just add final to that line.
```

Or you could increase the scope of the infoDialog.

```
public class YourActivity {

    private AlertDialog mInfoDialog;

    private YourMethod() {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_dialog, null);

        mInfoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                                           .setView(view)        
                                           .create();
        mInfoDialog.show();  

        Button submitBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);

        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mInfoDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
final AlertDialog infoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                                       .setView(view)        
                                       .create();
```

Comment: any other way to get rid of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog infoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                                         .setView(view)
                                         .setPositiveButton("ok", /*OnClickListenerGoesHere*/)    
                                         .create();
```

will solve your problem as well as dismiss the dialog when the button is being clicked.

Comment: But the thing is in my project, I need to avoid to use dialog default button

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that, since that's what an `AlertDialog` is designed for. But as others state you can simply add a `final` to the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

make the infoDialog  as private member of class or add the final keyword ahead as 
 final AlertDialog infoDialog = new AlertDialog(...)