# Cannot dismiss dialog with custom buttons

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How can I dismiss my custom dialog ? I get an error with `.cancel()` and `.dismiss()` as if they are not resolved outside the native `.setpositive/Negative button`

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825272/dismiss-a-custom-dialog) answer but still not working..

this is my dialog code :

```
public void showSettingsAlert(){

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
    final View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gps,null);
    alertdialog.setView(customView);
    alertdialog.setCancelable(true);
    FlatButton bouton_ok = (FlatButton)customView.findViewById(R.id.custom_ok_button);
    FlatButton bouton_quitter = (FlatButton)customView.findViewById(R.id.custom_cancel_button);

    bouton_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mcontext.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    bouton_quitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //to close the whole application : 
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    alertdialog.show();
}
```

On my host activity, this is how I check if gps was enabled or not :

```
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    // check if GPS enabled
    if(gps.canGetlocation() ){
        //stuff...
    }else{
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AlertDialog.Builder is used to build the alert dialog. After that, the create() method returns an AlertDialog object, which allows you to call dismiss().

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.brush_opts_dialog,null);
builder.setView(dialogView);

closeBtn = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);

final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

closeBtn .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
});

dialog.show();
```

Comment: I still cannot dismiss the dialog         `final AlertDialog dialog = alertdialog.create();
        bouton_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mcontext.startActivity(intent);
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });`

Comment: none :/ the dialog just does not close..but when i put back the native setpositivebutton the dialog closes right after i click on the "settings" button. i think it's because the setpositivebutton has `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`. on my custom button i have `new View.OnClickListener()`. What do you think Farouk ?

Comment: my bad ! i was showing the builder instead of the alertdialog itself !

Comment: Same problem, very frustrating! Wasted tons of time on it, really got to watch out for builder's create() vs dialog's create(). Solved the same way as you did, RidRoid.